# Advent of Code 2017 Day 3 (part 1) in Functional Programming (FP)

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I wanted to practice functional programming (FP) without using any library but using vanilla JS only. So I took a problem from Advent of Code.

https://adventofcode.com/2017/day/3

> You come across an experimental new kind of memory stored on an
>   infinite two-dimensional grid.
>
> Each square on the grid is allocated in a spiral pattern starting at a
>   location marked 1 and then counting up while spiraling outward. For
>   example, the first few squares are allocated like this:

```
  17  16  15  14  13
  18   5   4   3  12
  19   6   1   2  11
  20   7   8   9  10
  21  22  23---> ...
```

> While this is very space-efficient (no squares are skipped), requested
>   data must be carried back to square 1 (the location of the only access
>   port for this memory system) by programs that can only move up, down,
>   left, or right. They always take the shortest path: the Manhattan
>   Distance between the location of the data and square 1.
>
> For example:
>
> Data from square 1 is carried 0 steps, since it's at the access port.
>   Data from square 12 is carried 3 steps, such as: down, left, left.
>   Data from square 23 is carried only 2 steps: up twice. Data from
>   square 1024 must be carried 31 steps. How many steps are required to
>   carry the data from the square identified in your puzzle input all the
>   way to the access port?
>
> Your puzzle input is still 289326.

My solution in FP is:

```
const getSquare = (b, n) => {
  const result = Math.pow(b, 2);
  if (n === 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  if (result >= n) {
    return b;
  }
  return getSquare(b + 2, n);
};
const seq = (m, n) => m > n ? [] : [m].concat(seq(m + 1, n));
const getDirection = (square, n) => {
  const steps = (square - 1) / 2;
  if (n === 1) return 0;
  const east = seq(Math.pow(square - 2, 2) + 1, Math.pow(square - 2, 2) +
    square - 1);
  const north = seq(east[east.length - 1] + 1, east[east.length - 1] +
    square - 1);
  const west = seq(north[north.length - 1] + 1, north[north.length - 1] +
    square - 1);
  const south = seq(west[west.length - 1] + 1, west[west.length - 1] +
    square - 1);
  const x_directions = [east, west];
  const y_directions = [north, south];
  const getSteps = getStepsOf(n);
  const xy_direction = getSteps(x_directions);
  const yx_direction = getSteps(y_directions);
  const addSteps = addXAndYSteps(steps);

  return xy_direction !== -1 ? addSteps(xy_direction) : addSteps(yx_direction);
};
const addXAndYSteps = steps => directions => {
  if ((directions + 1) > steps) {
    return steps + ((directions + 1) - steps);
  } else if ((directions + 1) === steps) {
    return steps;
  } else {
    return steps + (steps - (directions + 1));
  }
};
const getStepsOf = n => directions => directions.reduce((res, direction) => {
  const position = direction.findIndex(dir => dir === n);
  return (position > -1) ? position : res;
}, -1);
const num = 289326;
const solution = n => getDirection(getSquare(1, n), n);
console.log("Total Steps: ", solution(num));
```

Is there a better way to write it in FP with pure JavaScript, i.e. no additional FP library? Any improvement suggestions are welcomed.